# Date Input restriction iPad

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, html, mobile-safari

So I am producing a **WEBAPP**, that needs to engage with iPad. There is a date input field in the application. On desktop browsers I am using the jQuery UI Datepicker, but for iOS I really like the 'wheels' that pop up natively when using the date input field: [image]

The problem is limiting the range. I can easily limit the range with the jQuery UI Datepicker via the minDate / maxDate options. And html5 date input fields are 'supposed' to have this function built in natively like so `<input type="date" min="2000-01-02" />`. However this has no effect on the iOS wheels. Is there a way I can do date range restriction WITHIN the iOS wheels?

**Whats the deal? Not one comment? Not one answer? There has to be a way to do this!**

Comment: I've been unable to find a solution to this either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is officially not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I just test and min and max works on Opera (but not on Opera for mobile ) and PlayBook browser.

Only one issue on Opera: the today button override the range.

If you really want to add a range you can use jquery + date.js(http://datejs.googlecode.com/files/date.js) and add a alert when you don't use a js datepicker

```
$("#bday").change(function(e){
  var d = Date.parse($(e.target).val());
  if ($(e.target).val().trim().length > 0 && d){
   if ($(e.target).attr("min") && d.compareTo(Date.parse($(e.target).attr("min")))== -1 ){
      alert("the date should greater than " +$(e.target).attr("min"));
      $(e.target).focus();
   }

   if ($(e.target).attr("max") && d.compareTo(Date.parse($(e.target).attr("max")))==1  ){
      alert("the date should greater than " + $(e.target).attr("max"));
      $(e.target).focus();
   }
 }
});​
```

Be careful I haven't had the time test it fully

Comment: I am not looking to place limits after the selection. I've got that already, I am looking for it to be disabled in the wheels themselves.